# Postgres: How do I safely remove a replica?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

Do I need to do anything on the primary if I permanently remove its only replica? I'm concerned about WAL files filling up the disk.

I want to remove the only replica from a single-node replication setup:

`P -> R`

I want to remove R.

Comment: actually it depends on recovery conf settings on `R`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your concerns are absolutely correct. Replica creates [replication slot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-replication-slots.html) on primary server, where `restart_lsn` is stored. According to the docs, `restart_lsn` is:

> The address (LSN) of oldest WAL which still might be required by the consumer of this slot and thus won't be automatically removed during checkpoints.

If replica does not advance LSN in this replication slot, primary will keep all WAL segments starting from this position and ignoring `max_wal_size` limit.

If you want to remove replica and enable WAL rotation, then you have to drop replication slot as well:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
postgres=# SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('replication_slot_name');
```

There is a [patch on Postgres Commitfest](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/23/1260/), which introduces new GUC to limit a volume of WALs held by replication slot. However, the patch is long-living and still not yet committed.

Comment: note: not all replicas do use replication slots - but this is still a good tip.